# How can I take back control of the uniswapV3 pool

Tags: token, solidity, erc20, uniswap

Earlier I released a token at 0x779084304ff90e8be79d5c4dbd1ca323b9ac555e and it has been listed on the uniswapV3 exchange. Since the wallet was stolen, I did a transferOwnership to a new wallet, but there was no transfer pool. Finally, I published the mnemonic of the old wallet. Someone used setApprovalForAll to transfer the ownership of my pool. How can I get my pool back?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, once an ownership is transferred to a new address, there's no taking back.

Unless the contract specifically allows it, which the Uniswap V3 pool does not.